# Is there a trope where a group of people get splattered with blood?

Tags: trope

I'm looking for a trope where there is a group of people and someone kills one person and blood/guts go everywhere and it splatters all over the audience.

Comment: what is a trope?

Comment: @dmikester1 Check out - http://tvtropes.org/. "Tropes are devices and conventions that a writer can reasonably rely on as being present in the audience members' minds and expectations." But be warned you can get lost on that site ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several tropes dealing with gore and blood splatter. [Ludicrous Gibs](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LudicrousGibs) for example is a trope for when there is simply an excess amount of gore (think Evil Dead). But I think closer to what you are referring to would be something more like [Gorey Discretion Shot](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoryDiscretionShot) combined with [Blood Spattered Innocents](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BloodSplatteredInnocents?from=Main.BloodSpatteredInnocents)

I think just about every episode of Supernatural starts this way.

Comment: Im trying to look for a gif that deals with an audience that gets splattered with blood. Something like glourus bastards or scary movie 3 with the funeral.

Comment: a gif is not a trope and google is your friend

Comment: it sounds like what you meant to ask for was a meme